# python: in parent class's method, call classmethod of that class, but bound to a child class

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes, class-method

Say I have the following code:

```
class Parent(object):
    classattr1 = 'parent'
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.foo()

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print cls.classattr1

class Child(Parent):
    classattr1 = 'child'

    def foo(cls):
        raise Exception("I shouldn't be here")

Child()
```

In `Parent.__init__`, I need to call 'foo' that is defined within Parent, but I need to call it bound to Child, so that accessing cls.classattr1 will actually access the attribute as it is overridden in Child.  Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Parent.foo.im_func(Child)
```

but looks kinda evil.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option:

```
class Parent(object):
    classattr1 = 'parent'
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.foo(self)

    def foo(self):
        print self.classattr1     # or self.__class__.classattr1

class Child(Parent):
    classattr1 = 'child'
    def foo(cls):
        raise Exception("I shouldn't be here")

Child()
```

`Parent.foo()` is not a class method anymore, but the end result should be the same as what you want.

```
>>> c = Child()    # prints 'child' by calling Parent.foo()
child
>>> c.foo()        # Child.foo() raises an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in foo
Exception: I shouldn't be here
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need `foo` to be a `classmethod`?  If not, this works.:

```
class Parent(object):
    classattr1 = 'parent'
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.foo(self)

    def foo(self):
        print self.classattr1

class Child(Parent):
    classattr1 = 'child'
    def foo(self):
        raise AttributeError("Wrong foo!")

Child()  # prints 'child'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the child class also needs to implement its own 'foo', so I can't do this. Indeed, that would've been much easier.

Comment: So both have different `foo`s, but when the parent class code is running, it needs to access its own `foo` and not the child's `foo`?  But the parent `foo` should be using the child's attributes?

Comment: Why do they need to be `classmethod`s?  If they don't, the updated code works.